# stanford corenlp -filelist from windows cmd prompt

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am using Stanford CoreNLP to output a list of files in conll format.   I have dozens of files to evaluate and would like to use the -filelist option as outlined in the Stanford CoreNLP documentation.    The logIds.text document has a list of 4 files, and all 4 files are located in my local Stanford CoreNLP folder.

I am trying to run the following code from the windows cmd prompt.  When I run this code, it returns the appropriate output file in conll format:

```
java -cp "*" -Xmx4g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP [ -props sampleProps.properties -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse,dcoref -writeOutputFiles -outputDirectory C:\Users\finleyc1\PycharmProjects\postPrepforConll ] -file 000001-ZZ
```

However, when I run the following code, it does not seem to recognize the logIds.txt file and instead defaults to a singe file named input.txt:

```
java -cp "*" -Xmx4g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP [ -props sampleProps.properties -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse,dcoref -writeOutputFiles -outputDirectory C:\...\postPrepforConll ] -filelist logIds.txt
```

Here is a key portion of the log:

Processing file C:...stanford-corenlp-full-2018-02-27\input.txt ... writing to c:....postPrepforConll\input.txt.output

Annotating file C:...stanford-corenlp-full-2018-02-27\input.txt ... done [0.4sec].

Is there an error in my code, or is there another way to iterate through a list of files?